# How to evaluate the following iterated integral

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

$$f(x,y)= \begin{cases} 2^{2n},\quad & 1/2^n \le x\le1/2^{n-1}, 1/2^n\le y <1/2^{n-1}\\-2^{2n+1}, \quad\ & 1/2^{n+1}\le x\le 1/2^n, 1/2^n \le y<1/2^{n-1}\ \\0, &\text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

How to evaluate the iterated integral
$$\int_0^1\left(\int_0^1f(x,y)~dy\right)~dx\ .$$

My attempt:

$$\begin{align*}\int_0^1\left(\int_0^1f(x,y)~dy\right)~dx &= \int_{1/2^{n}}^{1/2^{n-1}}\left(\int_{1/2^n}^{1/2^{n-1}}2^{2n}~dy\right)~dx+\int_{1/2^{n+1}}^{1/2^{n}}\left(\int_{1/2^{n}}^{1/2^{n-1}}-2^{2n+1}~dy\right)~dx \\ &= \int_{1/2^{n}}^{1/2^{n-1}}(2^{2n}\cdot(1/2^{n}))~dy\ + \int_{1/2^{n+1}}^{1/2^{n}}(-2^{2n+1}\cdot(1/2^{n}))~dy \\ &=\int_{1/2^{n}}^{1/2^{n-1}}2^n~dy\ +\int_{1/2^{n+1}}^{1/2^{n}}-2^{n+1}~dy\\ &= 0 \end{align*}$$

However, the answer should be $1$. What's wrong with my attempt?

Comment: I haven't checked your work, but I don't get what you're asking. If the answer should be zero and you got zero, why do you think something is wrong?

Comment: @Bungo Sorry, it's a typo and the answer should be 1.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the clarification. I don't see anything wrong with your work, except a typo in the second integral on the second line ($2^n$ should be $1/2^n$) which doesn't affect the rest. Also, plugging in $n=1$ and computing the integrals geometrically gives $4(1/2)(1/2) - 8(1/4)(1/2) = 0$, which agrees with your answer. What makes you think the answer should be $1$?

Comment: Wait, does the formula refer to a specific $n$, or does it mean "for all $n \in \mathbb N$"?

Comment: @Bungo I found the problem in a book and the answer is 1. Actually, it's a proof problem. I need to show $\int_0^1\left(\int_0^1f(x,y)~dy\right)~dx\ \neq \int_0^1\left(\int_0^1f(x,y)~dx\right)~dy\ .$ The integral $\int_0^1\left(\int_0^1f(x,y)~dx\right)~dy\ = 0.$

Comment: I'm guessing that what it intends is that the formula in the problem statement defines $f_n(x,y)$, and then $f(x,y) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n(x,y)$. Because clearly the two iterated integrals will be equal if you're just integrating the function as stated (for fixed $n$).

Comment: @Bungo I think it means for all $n \in \mathbb N.$